# Empty Playlists in Pytube

Tags: python, pytube

I was trying to work with a playlist in Pytube, but my playlist was always shown to be empty by Pytube even though there are videos in my playlist. I'm running the latest version of pytube (10.8.5). Is there any way to fix this? I've tried the regex answer, but it didn't work for me.

I would greatly appreciate any answer!

Here is the code that I was testing:

```
from pytube import Playlist

playlist = Playlist("https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLBN5m5aVVqE7kCNHZN-NBHDUIdnpp0XU_")
print(len(playlist.video_urls)) #Returns 0 even though there are 2 videos in my playlist
```

Comment: Hey bro... If the answer was what you were looking for, maybe you could accept it as the answer to help persons who would have the same problem and came looking. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What could be the problem is the playlist itself that you are trying to access... If the playlist has been set to private on YouTube then you won't get any details from it, while on the other hand if the playlist was set to public then you will get details from it.

I've created two playlist to use as example...

Private Playlist:

```
from pytube import Playlist

playlist = Playlist("https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-gXZHm4upIs5_28uuBOjWwxcldN8ZBDG")
print(len(playlist.video_urls))  # This will print 0...
```

Public Playlist:

```
from pytube import Playlist

playlist = Playlist("https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-gXZHm4upIvf2Dvq6GQHcC_HiavwUkl1")
print(len(playlist.video_urls))  # This will print 1...
```

So for the playlist you have created, in order to download from it you will have make it accessible and set public.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much! This solved my problem. Sorry about the top answer thing. I didn't see your answer until now.

Comment: You're welcome bro! Glad I could help. :-)